# How can I adjust where in the lane Kia Lane Assist will place my car?

Tags: kia, self-driving

I have a 2007 Kia Optima 3 estate, and one of the features that can be useful on long motorway journeys is the Lane Keep Assist System, or LKAS. In basic config it alerts when I cross a line, and this works perfectly, so the LKAS is definitely picking up lane markings correctly. In proactive mode it will guide the car to stay in lane, and I see from various posts online it should keep the car in the middle of the lane.

Mine, however, keeps the car very close to the right hand side of my lane - and being in the UK this is rather scary, as it's close to oncoming traffic if I'm on a normal road. It also doesn't guide the car gently round bends, instead it seems to wait until it is very close to the edge of the lane and then put a rather large jerk in to the steering, so long corners end up feeling like a series of straight lines with hard corners between them.

Is there a way to configure it to stay central within the lane?

Comment: That sounds like its learning... is it adaptive or that is what you get?

Comment: Sounds frightening... not in proper control of the vehicle. If you hit another vehicle, whose fault will that be? Oncoming traffic... the centre line might run out at a crucial moment. Isn't "proactive mode" supposed to be for when you fall asleep or something, not actually **driving** towards oncoming traffic so you can read the newpaper.

Comment: @WeatherVane there seem to be a lot of drivers who need to follow that centre line... not capable of positioning their vehicle otherwise...

Comment: @SolarMike I used to get a lift to work with a chap who could only drive in straight lines with sharp kinks. It might have had something to do with the battery powered record player he kept on the back seat...

Comment: It isn't learning - it's what you get. And yes, it is supposed to be an "assist" - so I wouldn't trust it for anything, but testing it shows up these things that concern me.

Comment: Perhaps a system designed more than 10 years ago is rudimentary and was never designed or intended to navigate a continous curve smoothly. Its response seems reasonable: turn away from the line, continue straight, detect the (as it happens) same line and repeat. Heck, self-driving cars are still being invented.

Comment: @weathervane - no, various folks report it working correctly and keeping the car centred

Comment: Indeed your actual question was about lane centring, not following a curve smoothly.